# MYSQL LIKE different behaviors for different languages, all tables utf8

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, sql-like

I have three tables each with 3 columns, they are identical to each other. Only difference is **se_words** created with `mysql` GUI and the other two are created programmatically thrue `sql` inside `mysql` GUI.

```
se_words
en_words
es_words
        -> id, name, user
```

I want to find words through the last 3 chars.

```
SELECT * FROM `es_words` WHERE word LIKE '%nar' // returns empty results (should be at least 500-1000+)
SELECT * FROM `en_words` WHERE word LIKE '%ate' // returns empty results (should be at least 500-1000+)
SELECT * FROM `se_words` WHERE word LIKE '%ens' // returns 1000+ results
```

The big problem is that **en_words** and **es_words** which are `utf8` (same as **se_words**) always returns *empty* result.

I have changed it to latin, utf8_bin, utf8_unicode_ci, latin_spanish_ci etc but it doesnt matter. Still gives *empty* result

**but**

if I change the sql code to just 1 char and procent sign on both sides, the code gives a result.

```
SELECT * FROM `es_words` WHERE word LIKE '%a%' // returns 10000+ results
SELECT * FROM `en_words` WHERE word LIKE '%a%' // returns 10000+ results
```

How come same sqlcode different tables returns different result when all columns has multiply values which should be returned on LIKE search?

**edit**

Few of the words that should be returned upon LIKE search

**es_words**

*abadernar,abaldonar,abanar,abandonar,abarrenar*

**en_words**

*aagate,abacate,abacinate,abalienate,abbate*

From the code with trimmed variables

```
SELECT w.id, w.word, w.user 
FROM en_words AS w 
WHERE w.word LIKE '%gel' ORDER BY LENGTH(word) ASC LIMIT 0,500
```

Comment: Perhaps there are no "en" words that end in "nar" and no "en" words that end in "ate".  You should also check that you don't have any additional characters at the end of the word (probably the real cause of this problem).

Comment: Such as spaces, full stops, etc.

Comment: Without seeing proper DDLs and sample data, it's really difficult to help.

Comment: [Seems to work fine here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e610ad/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an *\r* followed from the dictonary. Could only see it through an SQL DUMP. PHP would not show it at all.
I hope it solves the problem for you in the future who encounter it

```
(943, 'abridgments\r', 0),
(944, 'abrikosov\r', 0),
(945, 'abrikossov\r', 0),
(946, 'abril\r', 0),
(947, 'abrim\r', 0),
(948, 'abrin\r', 0),
(949, 'abris\r', 0),
(950, 'abristle\r', 0),
```